# Reading style names in table cell of doc file in Apache-POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am able to read the table cells, But I wanted **also to read the applied style name** of each cell of a row in a table. How can I achieve this?

EDIT

Following is the code snip which I have tried. By this I am able to read cell text also the applied pstyle(para style), but not able to read the rstyles.

```
private static void processDoc(String path) throws Exception {
        POIFSFileSystem fis = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(path));
        HWPFDocument wdDoc = new HWPFDocument(fis);
        // list all style names and indexes in stylesheet
        /*for (int j = 0; j < wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles(); j++) {
            if (wdDoc.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(j) != null) {
                System.out.println(j + ": " + wdDoc.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(j).getName());
            } else {
                // getStyleDescription returned null
                System.out.println(j + ": " + null);
            }
        }*/

     // set range for entire document
        Range range = wdDoc.getRange();     
        for (int i = 0; i < range.numParagraphs(); i++) {
            Paragraph p = range.getParagraph(i);
            // check if style index is greater than total number of styles
            if (wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles() > p.getStyleIndex()) {
                //System.out.println(wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles() + " -> " + p.getStyleIndex());
                StyleDescription style = wdDoc.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(p.getStyleIndex());
                String styleName = style.getName();
                // write style name and associated text
                System.out.println(styleName + " -> " + p.text().replaceAll("[\u0000-\u001f]", ""));
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n" + wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles() + " ----> " + p.getStyleIndex());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just reading the style from the table cell run as you'd do for a regular paragraph?

Comment: What about if you fetch the tables and their contents, rather than the Paragraphs? eg via [getTable(Paragraph)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Range.html#getTable%28org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph%29)

Comment: I am checking the condition for the para is in table (i.e tablePar.isInTable()). And when I try to get style index of the CharacterRun as cell.getParagraph(0).getCharacterRun(0).getStyleIndex() returning same index value as I got for para style index. If you want to share the example file I will do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [WordExtractor from Apache Tika](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordExtractor.java) is able to pull out the styles on a table, maybe look at the code there?

Comment: Sorry to ask this question, I have look at into that file and I am bit confuse to how I use that WordExtractor from Apache Tika my requirement?.

Comment: It has code that uses Apache POI for pulling out styles from various paragraphs, including tables, you may find the code you need in there